# How compute encrypt and decrypt time complexity for algorithm?

Tags: performance, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I try calculate time complexity for the following algorithm.

```
private void encrypt()
{
        M = new BigInteger(64,random);
        C = M.multiply(k).mod(N); // O(n^2)    
}

private void decrypt()
{
        kk= k.modinverse(N); // O(n^3)
        Mp = kk.multiply(c).mod(N); //O(n^2)
}
```

Have I calculated time complexity right?

Where time complexity for encrypt is O(n^2)
and time complexity for decrypt is O(n^3) + O(n^2) = O(n^3)

Comment: Since this is presumably homework you should firstly justify your calculations before we comment. Otherwise it looks like you are just looking for someone to do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis could be **more detailed** and **use better bounds** for number multiplication. It should contain more elaboration on where did you get complexities of used procedures.

For multiplying big numbers you can use [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) getting to `O(n^1.585)` or lower (see linked wikipedia pages for details).

Constructing a new integer and calculating a result modulo `N` would have complexity no worse than linear.

Therefore, complexity of `encrypt` procedure would **depend on chosen multiplication algorithm**.

The same goes for `decrypt()` procedure. I don't know where did you get complexity for `modinverse`. [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) can be calculated in at most `O(n^2)`.

The complexity given in the wikipedia page for modular inverse is given as `O(log(M)^2)`, which is expressed using value of the number, for which, we compute the inverse. Your analysis (as it is usually done when dealing with number theory algorithms) uses number lengths instead of their value, what makes the complexity `O(N^2)`.